# Does FindInstance traverse the entire domain?

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

If the result of `FindInstance[expr<=0,vars,dom]` is empty set, can it mean that `expr` is always greater than `0` in `dom`? I am wondering if `FindInstance` traverse the entire domain?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `expr` may be indeterminate for some values of `vars` from `dom`. I leave an example on your own. In some cases `FindInstance` does not traverse the entire domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page states that "When there are no solutions, `FindInstance` returns an empty list" (not quite an answer to your question but close). Also, there are cases where the command returns

```
`FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are 
 insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.`
```

This suggests (but does not clearly indicates) that the answer to your question is that when the command returns `{}` it means that there are no solutions in the domain.

However this does not mean that such a negative result comes from exploring the whole domain: Just think of

```
FindInstance[x^k + y^k == z^k && x >= 1 && y >= 1 && k >= 3 , 
{x, y, z, k}, Integers]
(* {} *)
```

Here the domain is infinite and therefore cannot be traversed in finite tine. The fact that `FindInstance` returns `{}` suggests the algorithm is aware of Fermat's last theorem.

If your question is specifically about inequalities just replace `x^k + y^k == z^k` by the equivalent `(x^k + y^k - z^k)^2 <= 0`.